# Is it okay to start a sentence or a clause with "a few times"?

Tags: grammar, syntax

Is it okay to start a sentence or a clause with "a few times" or should I rather move it to the end of it?

For example should I say:

> **A few times** I had her stand at the wall, but she never took that as a
>   kind of punishment and often treated that as fun, instead.

or:

> I had her stand at the wall **a few times**, but she never took that as a
>   kind of punishment and often treated that as fun, instead.

?

Comment: *A few times is fine, but too often is too much.* It's more natural in that sentence than in the first sentence in the question. (And, in fact, the sentence in this comment would lose at least some of its meaning if you tried to rephrase it.)  But there's nothing ungrammatical about the version in the question.

Comment: @JasonBassford Of course "a few times" in your example is fine -- it's subject of the sentence and thus is in its normal position before the verb. But in the OP's example, "a few times" is placed before the subject when its normal position would be after the verb, and is thus a preposed adjunct, probably fronted for emphasis.